# Не запускается git gui

Tags: git, git-bash

Когда запускаю git gui через git bash (git gui &) выводится вот такая ошибка. [image: изображение ошибки] Команды в git bash с этим репозиторием полностью работает ( pull push commit и тд.) При создании нового репозитория ошибка остаётся.

Comment: Пожалуйста, старайтесь приводить текст ошибки в виде текста, а не картинки.

Comment: Я понимаю, но вся ошибка состоит и директории моего репозитория, я не думаю что кому то поможет лучше понять мою ошибку если я текстом укажу свою ошибку

Comment: Как раз таки наоборот!